# Where did the phrase "diddly-squat" come from?

Tags: etymology, minced-oaths

It sounds like something [Ned Flanders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ned_Flanders) would say.

I believe it just means "nothing at all". But what are the origins of the phrase? Is it common in the US as well as the UK?

Comment: I think, if it's common in the UK, it must have been *borrowed* from the US.

Comment: @ pavium. Oh ok. "Borrowed" implies we're going to give it back. "Stolen" is probably more accurate. :-)

Comment: @Urbycoz: But "stolen" implies that UK removed it from US. "Shared" is probably most accurate. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is what I've found on the net about this phrase:

> The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang lists the
>   original form as "Doodly-squat," dating from 1934. No clue given as to
>   the origin. Doodle means, variously, a fool, a Union soldier, a penis,
>   to cheat, and to copulate. The dic does not list a usage for
>   "doodly-shit" until 1966.
>
> The dic lists "diddly-squat" as a euphemism for "diddly-shit," which
>   does not appear until 1964 (1963 for diddly-squat).
>
> It is difficult to draw a conclusion from all this, except I doubt it
>   has anything to do with squatting in a dwelling.
>
> *Dave Wilton, posting in alt.usage.english*

I have also found an interesting story about the [etymology of the phrase](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100116045609AA9lwdc).

(Editorial note: The copied story has been removed because of questionable copyright use. Also, the linked story is a **joke** and not a true etymology of the phrase.)

Comment: This sounds like a version of the Jack Schitt joke.