# The origin of the word, aw-shucks

Tags: etymology, contemporary-english

I was drawn to the word *aw-shucks* appearing in the following paragraph of the latest article which I forgot to take note of the source:

> “You know, I’m new to this campaign. Honestly, I never thought I would
>   be standing here. I thought I would be spending this evening with all
>   my friends in the great state of Indiana,” Indiana Gov. Mike Pence
>   said in his RNC debut tonight. His *aw-shucks* approach went over well
>   with delegates outraged by Ted Cruz’s refusal to endorse GOP nominee
>   Donald Trump earlier in the night.

I was totally unfamiliar with the word “aw-shucks,” and found out the following definition in the free dictionary:

awshucks adj. seeming to be modest, self-deprecating, or shy: 
[C20: from the US interjection aw shucks, an expression of modesty or diffidence]
Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014

Google Ngram shows that the word emerged in mid 1940, and its usage has been on a rapid increase to 0.00000136% level in 2000.

I’m curious to know the currency level and origin of this word. Does this word often apper in conversation and writings? How did the word that sounds as if like the exclamation, “Oh shock” come into American, informal, and in particular, adjective word?

Comment: It's actually two words -- "aw" and "shucks".  "Aw" is just a sort of embarrassed interjection and is essentially onomatopoeia.  "Shucks" (which is not the same as "shuck") is hard to define, but roughly means "it ain't nothing".  I've no idea what the etymology of "shucks" is.  The words easily go back 100 years.

Comment: I’ve now supplied separate citations from Merriam-Webster, from Oxford University Press, and from one other published (read: in print, not online) source that this is in origin a minced oath. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

## *“Aw shucks, we still don’t know squat!”*

When I first read your question, my reaction was that surely this must be explained in every dictionary.  But you know what? It isn’t! That must make it confusing to the non-native speaker. The short story is that *shucks* is a euphemism for *shit*, making “aw shucks” a watered-down version of “oh shit” that has long ago lost its harsh overtones.

#### *The Merriam-Webster New Book of Word Histories*, Merriam-Webster, 1991

The *Merriam-Webster New Book of Word Histories* (published by Merriam-Webster, 1991) explains its origin as a euphemism at length [on page 249](https://goo.gl/Ha9Jdj):

> All languages and cultures seem to have words or practices that are taboo and hence are not mentioned in polite society. Perhaps because of the shock produced when such words are used, many of them have come to function as interjections, the meaning of which is subordinated to their emotional impact. Another result of the social restrictions against using taboo words is the creation of euphemisms that can be used more freely, though naturally much of the intended force may be lost of this substitution.
>
> [...]
>
> As can be seen from many of the examples above, the initial sounds of the taboo words are often retained, and the euphemism is created by changing other parts of the word or by using other words that are not taboo and which begin with the same sounds. Thus we have *darn* and *darnation* as euphemism for *damn* and *damnation*. ***Shoot* used as an interjection is a euphemism for *shit*, as are *shucks* and *sugar*.**

#### Wikipedia

[Wikipedia tells the same story under its entry for *shit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit), albeit more briefly:

> The word *shit* (also *shite* in British and Hiberno-English) is usually avoided in formal speech. Minced oath substitutes for the word shit in English include *shoot*, *shucks*, and "sugar".

So it’s a simple story though, really. The word *shucks* falls into the category of a [*minced oath*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath), much like *gosh, darn, dang, heck, shoot, crud, frick*, and so many others. That is, it originated (quoting Wikipedia here) as

> ...a euphemistic expression formed by misspelling, mispronouncing, or replacing a part of a profane, blasphemous, or taboo term to reduce the original term's objectionable characteristics.

#### *English Lexicogenesis*, Oxford University Press, 2014

On [page 122 of *English Lexicogenesis*](https://goo.gl/J6TmIh) (Oxford University Press, 2014) D. Gary Miller writes, placing its origin at 1843:

> Certain body parts are suspect to tabu replacement; cf. *butt(ocks)* [*a.*1300], *rear (end)* [1851], *posterior* [1605], *derrière* [1774], *gluteus maximum* [n.d.]. Among bodily functions, there are **such euphemistic deformation as *shucks* [1843],** *shoot* [1934] for *shit*, and even *dipstick* [1968] for ‘penis’ and for *dipshit* [1963].

#### *Expletive Deleted: A Good Look at Bad Language*, Free Press, 2005

One [page 100 of *Expletive Deleted: A Good Look at Bad Language*](https://goo.gl/RtGHyb) (Free Press, 2005), Ruth Wajnryb writes:

> Once again, the word is serving a multitude of master. In addition, the **euphemisms that can replace SHIT (“sugar,” “shoot,” “shucks,”** etc.) serve both the general positive use and the negative ones. If ever we needed an example of how meaning is achieved through particular circumstance, SHIT is it.

The positive and negative of uses of *shucks* exactly match those of *shit*, as Wajnryb rightly points out.

---

You can see where it comes from when you see it in phrases like the example given by [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/shuck) for it:

> - “Thank you for getting it.” “Oh, shucks, it was nothing.”

Or from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shucks):

> - Because he was worried about his diary – shucks, only a notebook, really – he took it with him.
>   —Trenhalle, John A MEANS TO EVIL

Collins defines this as

> something of little value (esp. in the phrase *not worth shucks*)

By now you have probably correctly surmised that it’s used exactly the same way that *shoot* often is. In other words, this usage originated as a minced oath for *shit*, although no one thinks anything profane, taboo, or rude by it any longer. That’s what happens with minced oaths: they lose their rudeness.

## Interjection versus Negative Polarity Item

You might feel that the injection *Aw shucks!* is somehow different from the [negative polarity item](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf) found in *not worth shucks*. Although the low-level part-of-speech classification as an interjection differs from the one in which it occurs as a negative polarity item, there’s no reason to think those have separate origins.

### Interjection

- No shit.
- Oh shit.
- Aw shit, it’s nothing to me.
- Aw shucks, it’s nothing to me.

### Negative Polarity Item

- That idea isn’t worth shit.
- That idea isn’t worth shucks.
- That idea isn’t worth squat.
- That idea isn’t worth [doodly-squat](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/35558/2085).
- That idea isn’t worth diddly-squat.
- That idea isn’t worth diddly.

By the time you get to the bottom, the taboo origin can appear to be completely lost. But the matter of using *shucks* as both injection and a linked negative polarity item is the same one of using *shit* as both those things.  As Professor observed:

> Despite the considerable progress that has been achieved over the last two decades, the bad news is that we know squat about the proper treatment of negation and polarity. But then, by the Law of the Excluded Middle, the good news must be that **we don't know squat** about the proper treatment of negation and polarity.
>
> —Laurence R. Horn, “Flaubert Triggers, **Squatitive Negation**, and Other Quirks of Grammar.” *Perspectives on Negation and Polarity Items*, ed. Jacob Hoeksema et al. John Benjamins, 2001)

## Pronunciation: *Aw shucks* ≠ *Aw shocks*

One last thing: in your question you mentioned *“aw shock”*. However, *shock* will never be pronounced the same as *shuck*.  The most common pronunciation of *shock* in North America is probably /ʃɑk/, although both /ʃɔk/ and /ʃɒk/ also occur frequently enough. That variation is due to various mergers between the vowels in [Wells’ canonical lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_UK_and_US_English) LOT, CLOTH, and THOUGHT in the many dialects of North American.

Those are the wrong lexical sets for *shucks* though. The pronunciation of *shucks* is /ʃʌks/. That means it has [the STRUT vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects).

At the risk of being crude, that means that *shucks* rhymes with *fucks*, a taboo word.  My own conjecture is that *shucks* as a euphemism for *shit* owes some of its appeal to the way it takes not only the front-end of *shit* but also the back-end of *fucks*, thereby doubling its allusion.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with corn shucks?

Comment: Do you have any references for its link to *shit*? Both the OED and [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=shucks) link it directly to *corn shucks*. Since those are quite useless, that seems like a very reasonable etymology without any *shit* or any other oaths. Minced or not.

Comment: @terdon References—and elaboration—now duly supplied. :)

Comment: I can't quite grasp the exact intended meaning from the quote in the question, but by far the most common colloquial use of _aw shucks_ in my experience is to express slight embarrassment and overwhelmedness at being complemented: “Wow, this lasagne is absolutely divine!” — “Aw, shucks, it's not that good!”. That doesn't seem minced to me, and replacing it with _shit_ completely changes the meaning. I feel fairly certain the OED is right about that usage at least—perhaps the two different usages really are different, or one arose on the basis of the other.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It works like “Aw, gee, it weren’t nuthin’” — which carries the very same sentiment in current usage yet originated as a minced oath for “Oh Jesus!”, a much stronger interjection. That’s what happens with euphemisms: over time they lose all connection with the thing they’re substituting for, becoming far milder. It seems obvious to me that both “don’t know shucks” and ”aw shucks” originate as “don’t know shit” and ”aw shit”. The idea that any of this has to do with corn husks rather than euphemisms for *shit* plain and simple seems like so much fanciful folk etymology.

Comment: @tchrist I don't see any reason to think the two etymologies are mutually exclusive. Minced oaths are not uncommonly based on actual words, rather than just simple modifications, especially if the meaning is appropriate. _Shoot_ and _shucks_ are both reasonable candidates to be used as euphemisms for _shit_, but _shibboleth_ or _Shivananda_ wouldn't be very obvious choices.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet [Back when the term originated, the number-one most common form of toilet paper in those parts was corn husks.](http://www.scotduke.com/2010/10/14/what-was-used-before-toilet-paper/)   Either that or [corncobs themselves](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/572/what-did-people-use-before-toilet-paper-was-invented). That’s going to be a powerful association between shit and husks.

Comment: @tchrist Yoicci is also looking for current usage patterns. 'Shucks' or 'aw shucks' is very informal (like most interjections). To me it sounds like a caricature of Southern or Appalachian or AAVE speech that is only heard in already outdated in rural 1950's. If someone were to use it now it would seem only as a parody of that speech.

Answer (score 4):

Two new entries in the *OED* [*OED Third Edition* (November 2010) - new entry; *OED Online* version June 2016] provide information on the development and origins of the interjection and adjective, 'aw shucks' (as well as 'aw-shucks', the verb derived from the interjection). The origin and etymology given for the interjection and adjective is

> **Origin:** Formed within English, by compounding. Etymons: *aw* int., *shucks*, *shuck* n.<sup>2</sup> 3.
>   **Etymology:** < *aw* int. + *shucks* (see *shuck* n.<sup>2</sup> 3).

["aw shucks, int. and adj.". *OED Online*. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/250153 (accessed September 18, 2016).]

The definition of the 'aw' part of the compound is the uncomplicated "An exclamation usually expressing mild remonstrance, entreaty, commiseration, disgust, or disapproval." For 'shucks', the situation is less simple.

> **shuck**, *n.*<sup>2</sup>
>   **Forms:**  Also *shock*.
>   **Frequency** (in current use): ++++....
>   **Etymology:** Origin unknown.
>   Chiefly *dial.* and *U.S.*
>   ....
>   **1. a.** A husk, pod, or shell; esp. the outer covering or strippings of Indian corn, chestnuts, hickory nuts, etc. See *corn-shuck* n. **b.** [etc.]
>   ....
>   **2.** As a type of something valueless.
>   ....
>   **3.** *pl.* as an *interj.* of contempt or indifference.

The progression from sense 1 to 3 suggests the line of development. Sense 1 refers to relatively valueless material. Sense 2 references the general type, 'valueless'. Sense 3 documents the use, in the plural, as an interjection expressing the idea of valuelessness.

For Sense 3, 'shucks' the plural as an interjection, the earliest attestation in *OED* is 1847. For the interjection 'aw', the earliest attestation in *OED* is 1852.

For the compound, 'aw shucks', the earliest attestation for use as an interjection is 1888; the earliest attestation for use as an adjective is 1932. This development, from earlier interjection to later adjective, may safely be understood as evidence of the adjectival utility of the sense expressed by the interjection.

Searches of other online sources did not reveal attestations earlier than those given by the *OED*.

---

About the currency of the term in spoken English, little pertinent external evidence is available to me. A case-insensitive search of the *NOW Corpus* of semi-informal English in online broadcast and print media reveals a fair number of uses of the adjective, 'aw-shucks': 24 in 2016, 23 in 2015, 23 in 2014, and so on. A case-insensitive search in the same corpus for 'aw shucks' reveals other uses in that form as an adjective as well as interjectional uses.

My own experience with spoken English also suggests that the term enjoys steady and widespread, although not overwhelmingly frequent, use. This is to be expected of a term that has *no connection with profane, blasphemous, taboo or otherwise objectionable terms,* and yet expresses borderline expletive indifference or mild contempt.

---

Locally (only at EL&U, so far as I can determine from available evidence), the quaint notion that 'shucks' (interjection) *originated* as a euphemism for 'shit' (interjection) seems to have some inexplicable traction. This notion is obviously anachronistic.

The earliest attested use of 'shucks' as an interjection was in 1847 (*OED Online*). The earliest attested use of 'shit' as an interjection was in 1865 (op. cit.). Therefore, suggesting that 'shucks' *originated* as a euphemism for 'shit' ignores the significantly earlier attestation of 'shucks'.

Comment: A comprehensive and thorough commentary of the meaning, usage and origin of the word in question.  It's helpful. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: @JEL Although this etymology is useful, I think that tchrist's actually right about this being a euphemism. [The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia](https://archive.org/stream/centurydictionar07whit#page/5603/mode/1up) suggests a similar etymology as the O.E.D., but it marks the word shucks as vulgar, and implies a connection to the vulgar phrase "not worth shucks". That sounds innocuous enough today, but given that we have both "Aw sh!t" and "Not worth sh!t", I recommend editing the last paragraph because it's likely that this is connected with an objectionable word.