# What are British English alternatives for “jack sh*t”

Tags: british-english

If you want to say e.g. "He does jack sh*t (nothing) at work", what British English idioms would you use (apart from just 'nothing')?

Comment: You might want to check out the other post about  jackshit: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362602/polite-version-of-they-dont-give-us-jacksht Although not specifically BrE. they may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious equivalent would be "f**k all" or, more politely, "sweet FA".

Another, less strong, alternative would be "bugger all".

Comment: Also "Sod all", "Naff all" and "Badger all" (although the last two are euphamisms or minced oaths for "f**k all" and "bugger all" respectively. Also don't forget that Dylan Thomas called the town in "Under Milk Wood" Llaregub because spelling Buggerall backwards looks Welsh!